# CSS can't set a bottom of the page margin

Tags: css, positioning, margin

I can't seem to find a way to put a bottom margin on the page. What I want to happen is the following: when you click one of the buttons and the thumbnails appear, that list should have a bottom margin so it's not stuck at the bottom of the page.

A lot of stuff is positioned with JavaScript; I don't know if that messes around with stuff.

My page: http://bit.ly/JV5I0Z

Surely there must be a way to set a bottom margin. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make something that is positioned at the bottom of the page, you have two options.

1 - position: absoulte; margin-top: 600px (example)
2 - Use javascript to get the browser height and then change the margin-top to what ever it should be.